# Javascript conditional statement and pass to form

Tags: javascript

I got a form and we changed the structure of how we are passing request variables from the jsp to the form bean.  Anyway here is an example:

Before I was doing this

jsp:

```
 <fieldset class="det">
        <legend>Closure Level</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="openLevel" >Open</input><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="phyCompLevel" >Physically Complete</input><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="finCompLevel" >Financially Complete</input>
    </fieldset>
```

Handler:

```
if ((form.isOpenLevel() == true) && (form.isFinCompLevel() != true && form.isPhyCompLevel() != true))
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("PHYS_COMP_DATE ","is","NULL"));
        }
        if ((form.isPhyCompLevel() == true) && (form.isFinCompLevel() != true && form.isOpenLevel() != true))
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("PHYS_COMP_DATE ","is","NOT NULL"));
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("FIN_COMP_DATE","is","NULL"));    
        }
        if ((form.isFinCompLevel() == true) && (form.isOpenLevel() != true && form.isPhyCompLevel() != true))
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("FIN_COMP_DATE","is","NOT NULL"));
        }
```

As you can see I was checking which boxes were "checked" to see what to pass to the bean.  We are pulling all the variables at once so I cant do any logic in the handler anymore.  So what I need to so is do this same type of logic in Javascript as I submit the form.  So something like this:

I need to do this condition in javascript:

```
if ((form.isOpenLevel() == true) && (form.isFinCompLevel() != true && form.isPhyCompLevel() != true))
        {
<input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria('PHYS_COMP_DATE').fieldName" value="PHYS_COMP_DATE"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria('PHYS_COMP_DATE').operation" value="is"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria('PHYS_COMP_DATE').values" value="NULL"/>
       }
```

If you can point me in the right direction..much appreciated.  I dont need all the conditions, just that first one as an example.

Comment: By the kind of boolean checking you are doing in the Handler code (only one true), consider using a radio button instead of a checkbox.

Comment: They can choose any como of the 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, to validate if an input type=checkbox is checked, you use the `checked` attribute. Also, is preferable to use IDs to refer to an HTML's element from javascript so you can take advantage of the `getElementById()` function. Example using your code with a little modification:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="openLevel" >Open</input><br/>
...
if(document.getElementById('openLevel').checked){
  ...
}
```